# Ansible | Variable declaration to bash script

Tags: ansible

I have a bash script under `files` which needs a variable to get passed from default\main1.yml. How can I declare the same?

```
roles
  config
    defaults
      main1.yml
    files
      script.sh
    tasks
      main2.yml
```

defaults\main1.yml

```
log_group_name: "{{ lookup('env','LOG_GROUP') }}"
```

script.sh

```
for NAME in $(ls -1p /home/ec2-user/ |grep -v "^_" | grep -v "/$" |cut -d. -f1);
do
if ! grep $NAME /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf;
then    
sudo tee -a /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf << END
[$DAGNAME]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/airflow/$NAME/*/*/*.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = $NAME
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = ${log_group_name}
END
fi
done
sudo service awslogsd start
sudo systemctl enable awslogsd
```

task/cloud.yml

```
---

- name: 'Cloud | AWSlogs.conf file'
  when: inventory_hostname == 'master'
  script: ../files/cloud.sh

- name: 'Cloud | AWSlogs.conf file'
  when: inventory_hostname == 'worker_1'
  script: ../files/cloud.sh
```

ansible command to execute the play:- deploy.py

```
execute(['sudo', '-E', 'ansible-playbook', 'ansible/plays/deploy.yml', '-i', 'hosts.yml'],
                stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, env=aug_env)
```

Comment: can you share the task where you are calling the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works -

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - shell: "script.sh {{ log_group_name }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable within the execution environment of the script, but it clearly already exists since you're pulling it out of the ENV so you don't even need to do that. If you did, you could install the script via the Ansible template module and execute the script that way.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the script's parameter

script.sh

```
log_group_name=$1
...
```

and run the script with the parameter

roles/config/tasks/main2.yml

```
- command: "{{ role_path }}/files/script.sh {{ log_group_name }}"
```

You probably know, but just to be sure. This will work with the "localhost" only. In other cases, the script must be copied to the "remote hosts" first and the path to the script must be changed.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I need to execute this on remote hosts. How can I copy them? Also I am using python to call the ansible playbook also getting my variable.